# GRUB screen appears after install

Tags: grub2

I installed UBUNTU 12.0 to run from USB (flash drive).  When I restarted I clicked to load UBUNTU and the GRUB screen appeared.  How do I get the OS to run/  I did the uninstall/reinstall thing but can not get the OS to run.  thank you

Comment: I don't believe there is a such version of Ubuntu as 12.0. There is only 12.04, and 12.10.

Answer (score 2):

If GRUB is appearing there is no problem, select Ubuntu to boot it.

And, there is nothing such as Ubuntu 12.0! It's either 12.04 or 12.10